# App run from tapping push notification is closing after clicking system back-button

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic3

The problem is what the title says, but it isn't happening if I click anywhere on the screen before. Looks like an application isn't active before click, that is why the registered back button action doesn't work. The code of the action:

```
private async registerBackButtonAction() {
  await this.platform.ready();
  this.backButtonHandler = this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
    // ...
  });
}
```

The back button works properly on every case but this one. Do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to re-register the handler on the app's **onResume**() event, this way if the app was loaded from memory, the backbutton handler will work again.